# ImageLoader displaying half an image

Tags: android, imageview

Some images I download consistently display only part of the image I try to download. The image size does not seem to matter.. It is caused by something else. Below is my config for getting the images.

```
ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(v.getContext())
                .defaultDisplayImageOptions(options)
                .threadPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY - 1) // default
                .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
                .memoryCacheSize(2 * 1024 * 1024)
                .memoryCacheSizePercentage(13) // default
                .discCacheSize(50 * 1024 * 1024)
                .build();

        imageLoader.init(config);
        imageLoader.displayImage("", holder.image);
        imageLoader.displayImage(url, holder.image, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                // Do whatever you want with Bitmap
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
                LogUtils.log("failed to load image: " + imageUri.toString() + " with reason: " + failReason.getCause().toString());
            }
        });
```

[image: half loading image]

The image should be fully loaded not half white.

What culd be causing this?

Thanks.

I am using Universal Image Loader by Nostra

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Comment: Did the issue occur on all images? I have something like that, but it occurs very scarcely. Only 1-2 images in around 70 and only once every 5-10 runs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

Basically wrapping content height was causing this problem (weird right?).

So instead I am just setting the dp value directly.

Thanks for the help :).